# How to get all row data from a javascript array converted from a mysqli_fetch_array() fetched array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to convert an array from PHP to Javascript.
My table has a lot of columns. The first 2 are id (INT) and name (VARCHAR).

This is my PHP code:

```
$sql = 'select * from foodlist';
$query1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$javascriptarray = mysqli_fetch_array($query1);
```

This is my javascript code:

```
var foodArray = <?php echo json_encode($javascriptarray) ?>;
```

First I tried this:

```
jQuery(this).val(foodArray.id);
```

It outputs the id of the first row. How do I produce the id of the second row?
Normally I would do something like this, but this produces nothing.

```
jQuery(this).val(foodArray[0]);
```

Thank you in advance for the help and tips.

Comment: How does foodArray look like ?

Comment: `foodArray.id[1]` if you're only looking for the id on the second row.  Otherwise, if you want the id from all rows, you would do that with a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that fetch_array only returns one row at a time. You need to loop through it with a while loop.

```
$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
    array_push($array, $row);
}
```

then in js..

```
var foodArray = <?php echo json_encode($array) ?>;
```

To validate print footArray to the console with `console.log(foodArray);` You'll see that what you currently have is just one row of results.

Comment: On php.net i saw it was array_push() not push_array().  Other than that it was a big help. This was the biggest obstacle holding my project back. Thank you very much for your help and your time.

Comment: Oops you’re right :) I’ll edit for other users. Glad I could help!